# The dual space $L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$ can't be identified with $L_1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

*Let be  $L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $L_1(\mathbb{R})$, prove that the dual space of $L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $[L_\infty(\mathbb{R})]^*$, can't be identified with $L_1(\mathbb{R})$, sp in other words:
$$\forall L\in [L_\infty(\mathbb{R})]^* \  \nexists g \in L_1(\mathbb{R}) : Lf=\int_\mathbb{R}fgdx, \ f\in L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$$*

Can you please help with this one? I don't know how to prove it.

A note: I define the spaces $L_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, $L_1(\mathbb{R})$, the norms $||f||_\infty$, $||f||_1$ of a lebesgue measurable functions  and the lebesgue measure on $L$ lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra as such:
$$|*|:L\rightarrow[0,+\infty]$$

$$||f||_\infty=\inf\{t\geq0 : |\{|f|>0\}|=0\}$$
$$||f||_1=\int_\mathbb{R}|f|dx$$

$$L_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})=\{f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{K} \ |  \ ||f||_\infty<+\infty\}$$
$$L_{1}(\mathbb{R})=\{f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{K} \ |  \ ||f||_1<+\infty\}$$

where every element of $L_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ or $L_{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is a equivalence class [f], denoted as $f$ to simplify, defined as:
$$[f]=\{g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{K} \ | f=g \ lebesgue-a.e.\}$$

Comment: Hint: Take the functional from the answer to your previous question and extend it to a bounded functional on $L^\infty$ using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is separable,  while $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable. Hence the dual of $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable, by a general theorem on Banach spaces.

Comment: @MaoWao ok, I'll try that